# Physical effort in outputting 5V 1–2A?

Tags: power-supply

I have an iPhone, and sometimes recharging it from a wall is inconvenient. Maybe I am on a long bus ride. If I am willing to do physical activity/exercise to produce power, how much effort would I need to exert to act as a phone charger, supplying a steady 1–2 amps at 5 V?

This hypothetical device would need to be small and light enough that I could carry it... no point in it if I have to be at home to use it.

For example, there’s a simple hand exercise device that you squeeze over and over to build hand muscle. How much power could that generate?

Comment: I won't say too much, but I will point to this link: https://newatlas.com/the-pedal-a-watt-stationary-bike-power-generator-create-energy-and-get-fit/13433/. It is a stationary bike. A person riding this can generate 200W of power - for your situation (5V @ 2A), that is only 10W of power - 5% of what the bike could generate. So I would take a gamble and say it is possible. But no idea how (probably more suited to a mechatronic/mechanical engineer).

Comment: Probably a more efficient hand device is a crank generator. These aren't squeeze devices, though, and I think they are all mounted in some fashion. But I've seen units ranging from 10 W to 65 W (though I don't know how long you or me might keep up with a 65 W generator.) Your total is 10 W, so crank devices exist in the right range for continuous, direct operation. Efficiencies can be as high, so I read, as 80%. But of course, human biomechanics has more/less efficient positions during a crank, and in any case humans are NOT efficient converters of energy, themselves. See Patent US7893551B2.

Comment: Google hand crank radio, see if you can get a power output figure?  You don't have to generate the full 10W, as long as you have USB port circuitry sophisticated enough to report how much current it can generate.

Comment: If you get one of those squeeze devices and measure the force it takes to squeeze, you can then estimate the power -- energy = force * distance, power = energy/time.  So figure out how much energy per squeeze, then figure out how fast you can squeeze the thing continually.  You'll want to switch off your right and left hands, or you'll look like Popeye on one side and Olivoil on the other.

Comment: Your biggest challenge will be keeping cool, not working up a major sweat.

Comment: You know those bikes in the gym often have watts settings and/or display. Check them out

Comment: Not answering the question but I would suggest buying a good quality power bank such as [this](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/accessories/20000-powerbank/) one from (Chinese phone maker) Huawei.

Comment: At some science museums around the world, they have an exercise bike that you can pedal and it will show you how many watts of electrical energy you generate. I found that powering a 60W light bulb was strenuous but possible. For your case, 5V * 2A = 10W, so it should be easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

20 watts delivered into a hand-cranked generator (enough to deliver 10 electrical watts after conversion losses) could be managed all day by a fit and motivated person. This would employ all of your arm muscles. However, you'd need reasonable length cranks, comfortable handles, a good secure mounting for the generator, it's not something you'd nonchalantly carry onto and use on a bus.

A grip-squeeze device could be rigged to generate some power but, only being able to use the small grip muscles in the forearm, you'd struggle to get more than a few watts for a few minutes before exhaustion.

If you don't mind standing, then a mini-stepper could be rigged with a generator. This would use your legs, so we're back in the sustained many 10s of watts, even 100+ region. It could lie stably on the floor, and maybe fit into a small backpack, so is probably the most suitable device overall. Consider that a 70kg individual walking up 200mm high steps one per second is delivering 140 watts.

Comment: I love the stepper idea. Best muscles to use, no mounting required.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider are you aware this will make the flooble-crank obsolete?

Comment: is there way to make it into a deadlift/squat machine? I guess, you fix bar to a generator via cable and pull it for repetitions.

Comment: The most convenient design to use at a desk or as a non-driver in a vehicle is probably something like a sewing machine or organ pedal, with a single piston rod driving the crank generator.

Comment: @Ale..chenski You are 9.81-fold off. 70kgf x 0.2m per second x 9.81 m per (second squared)(to get to Newtons from kgf) = 137.34 watts, which is less than the 140 I first claimed, but, hey, to an engineer, 9.81 **is** 10. Whoops, that site you linked is 9.81-fold off, so the arithmetic isn't your fault. But who goes to a web calculator, and blindly trusts it?

Comment: @Neil_UK, yep, my fault, forgot that the mass should be converted into Newtons...The web calculator is correct, my interpretation of (kgf m/s) was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Neil_UK’s mention of hand grip strength training devices made me curious how much power your hands could provide. To get an estimate I looked up such devices, apparently they usually provide about 500N of resistance over a distance of 6cm. This gives us about 30J of mechanical energy per squeeze. Not sure how many squeezes you can do per second, so let’s go with energy. A NiMH AA battery cell stores about 12kJ of electricity, **so you’d need 400 squeezes to charge a single NiMH AA battery**. Good luck with that! And this calculation doesn’t even account for losses.

As Neil_UK also mentions, arm and leg muscles are much stronger. Even an untrained person can output 100W on a bicycle over long durations (>1h).

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the force is not 500N (that would roughly be the weight of a cement bag).

Comment: 500N grip, wow, I don't want to shake hands with you! I shook one guy's hand and asked him 'are you a drummer, or a karate expert?' He grinned, and said he was a canoeist.

Comment: Actually, accoding to [this study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50224866_Grip_force_and_pinch_grip_in_an_adult_population_Reference_values_and_factors_associated_with_grip_force) 500N seems to be common among men, while for women it's 200N less.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Interesting paper. While 500N might be a peak grip strength, I think a lower figure is appropriate to power generation, which would require an average force over a long travel. I see that they compared one with three grip trials, and noted grip fatigue being a problem in the three trial. At least I know now to avoid shaking hands with Norwegians

Comment: Thanks for finding and linking the paper. The training devices usually state 30 – 150lbs or even 300lbs (1500N). For strength training you’d usually do ~3 to ~15 reps, so yes, fatigue would be a problem if you need to do 400 of them ;)

Answer (score 2):

10 watts compared to the 550 foot-pounds and 746 watts of ONE Horsepower, gives us useful numbers.

You need to lift 550 foot-pounds * 10/746 = 550 * 1/75 ~~ 8 pounds lifted up ONE FOOT, every second.

Can you lift a gallon of water, every second, up one foot, for an hour?

Comment: How much is this in SI-units?

Comment: @Suppen if you lift a two-liter bottle half a meter up every second, that'll be about 10 watts: 2L*1kg/L*10m/s^2*0.5m*1Hz=10W.

Comment: Lifting things is not a great analogy, because humans exert energy even if no work is done on an object (imagine holding that two-liter bottle above your head for an hour). There's a good reason that human power is often measured in bicycling output power.

Comment: Point is the OP must perform this task until the battery is charged.

Answer (score -2):

Technically, a person with mass of 100 kg walking in 1-m steps at 2 m/s (about 4.5 miles per hour) has to generate/use about 500 W of power, as [this article](http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/technote/walkrun.htm) illustrates. So if you have some device embedded into your shoes, harvesting extra 10 W should be doable, especially since you need the charge for 1 hour only (smartphone batteries have about 10 W-hr capacity, and if we neglect conversion losses). So adding 2% load to the walking effort should do the job. How comfortable these shoes will be is another question.

There were [attempts](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-30816255) to use the energy harvesting inside shoes, but the results were not very impressive, 3-4 mW.

There are even [instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/Power-Generating-Shoe/) how to make "shoe generator" out of parts from rechargeable flashlight, so this method likely generates more than few milliwatts.

RECONSIDERATION AND CORRECTIONS: This answer brings to attention that not only a "hand grip" is available for power harvesting by lifting something, but footwork has some capabilities too. The above expectations are however overly optimistic.

(1) a 4.5 mph is a good 5K Marathon walk, and it's not for an average person to accomplish it in 1 hour. So yes, it is a "brisk walk" indeed, or like biking on the Tour de France;

(2) observationally, walking requires lifting a person's center of mass by 2-3cm only, not as a 1-meter stiff spoke rolling over without a rim as the cited model suggests. Therefore, the mechanical power of a 2-step per second walk seems to be of the order of 2 x 100 x 0.03 x g ~= 60 Watts. (this doesn't address how much a person should eat to achieve this).

(3) Therefore, a power-generating shoe must have a 0.5 cm excursion plunger to generate 10 W from a 100-kg fast-walking body assuming 100% efficiency.

(4) Worse, the efficiency of crank generators, even if made by [best military engineers](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a433537.pdf), doesn't exceed 50%, so the shoes must have a 1-cm excursion shoe to generate 10 W.

(5) Therefore a 10-W crank generator, if embedded into a shoe, will consume about 15-20% of fast walking efforts, which might be not comfortable.

(6) See also a [quite related answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/121224/117785) on EE Stack Exchange about efforts to generate electricity.

CONCLUSION: The task to charge a smartphone in one hour using muscle power would require a very dedicated and physically fit person.

Comment: Nothing you write here supports the 10W or even close to it that OP actually asks about. The "instructable" doesn't even show that it works.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: _"a person with mass of 100 kg walking in 1-m steps at 2 m/s (about 4.5 miles per hour) has to generate/use about 500 W"_ - Those numbers seem suspect. [This source](http://bodytransform.co/Blog/Power+output+during+exercise.html) puts Tour de France runners at 500W continuous (which matches reasonably with what I've read before). That means your big guy walking quickly would expend the same power as a Tour de France athlete, which I doubt. Your article also makes all sorts of incorrect assumptions: legs are rigid poles, energy of the downward motion is lost instead of recovered.

Comment: 500W is 120 calories per second. I did a charity walk a couple of days ago, sustaining about 2m/s for an hour, and I weigh 100kg. There's no way that I burned 400,000 calories, so this model must be way off. Most exercise calculators would put that in the 500-1000 calorie range, so I'd be generating no more than a couple of watts.

Comment: @PhilG Are you sure you're not confusing calories and kilocalories? The latter are often, confusingly, written as "Calories"? 400kcal isn't a huge amount of energy: it's about one sixth of the recommended daily intake.

Comment: I'm confused. 500W does seem ridiculously high compared to the power output of cycling but, assuming that the walking calculators are all giving outputs in kcal rather than cal, walking at 2m/s (which is a, admittedly, a _very_ brisk walk -- about 4.5mph or 7.2km/h) does seem to burn about 400-600kcal/hour for a 100kg person, which is 465-700W. The discrepancy might be that cyclists measure power at the crank, whereas the walking analysis tries to include some of the inefficiencies of walking, such as having to pick up your back leg and move it forwards for the next stride.

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog, how does this answer the question? Simple: people calculated the equivalent amount of work as lifting 4 kg on 30 cm each second. I just bring to attention that a walking person lifts 100 kg over several cm every second when walking. So there is already some mechanism that can be utilized other then using arms to do the work. I don 't understand the hostility to this answer.

Comment: @PhilG 400kcal for an hour of walking sounds pretty plausible actually. But there's a big difference between the energy _consumed_ in food, and the energy delivered as mechanical work. The OPs question refers to the latter, but this comment thread has evolved to the former. I think this is also what threw me off when interpreting Ale..chenski's answer (which helps conflate the two in _"generate/use about 500 W"_)...

Comment: So let's try and get this back on track. [This source](https://dothemath.ucsd.edu/2011/11/mpg-of-a-human/) puts human efficiency at 25%, [this SO answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46788) says 20%. Let's go with 25%. David Richerby's 700W for the walk would then translate to 175W of mechanical output; 35% of the Tour de France cyclists for the - indeed - very brisk walk. This explains the discrepancies we were seeing well enough. It's unclear though if Ale..chenski's source is referring to mechanical output or caloric uptake, but 500W output still seems too high to me.

Comment: Apologies, yes, the calculators I used didn't make that distinction.

Comment: @marcelm, I wonder how the downward motion is recovered and not lost? Human body is not made of steel springs last time I checked...

Comment: @Ale..chenski Not steel, but bone, muscles, and tendons are elastic to some extent. As far as I know, the human body uses this to recover energy from downward motion (which makes sense, as there was a significant evolutionary pressure to preserve energy). To be clear, I'm not claiming 100% of energy is recovered; I don't know how much, but _some_ is. Key quote from [a random paper](http://hpl.bme.unc.edu/sawickietal_ESSR_2009_springinstep.pdf): _"Elastic energy storage and return in the Achilles tendon during each step enhance the efficiency of ankle muscle-tendon mechanical work ..."_

Comment: @marcelm, yes, bio-mechanics has some special quirks, and tendons feel somewhat elastic when occasionally trying to chew them. Although Dictionary defines them as "a flexible but inelastic cord of strong fibrous collagen tissue". Stepping on shoes with built-in cranks will be like stepping uphill, and your nice article mentions that  "walking up a steep slope (where elastic energy storage and return are assumed to be negligible)...", so there are many angles to explore. Peace.